# Mixing two fluids dynamically using valves and sensors

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor, solenoid-valve

I'm new to the field of electrical and electronics design... trying to build a hobby project for home decoration. I want to mix two colored fluids with proportion of each liquid decided by a user input (a slider or touch sensor?). The liquids in two tanks will be mixed on the fly and pushed out whenever a proximity sensor detects a movement nearby. The valve shall remain open for a couple of seconds or so.

My background is software development. But I have a feeling that this can be done with simple electrical/electronics circuit without any software.

1. Is this indeed feasible with only electrical circuit?
2. Can anyone please suggest a good starting point? @Reroute suggested a use of 555 timer which I'll have a look into.
3. What are the caveats to keep in mind while designing such a circuit in terms of failure points?

Regards

Comment: This could likely be approached with a dual potentiometer and a push button, and 2 monostable oscillator circuits, e.g. the old 555 timer, when triggered, both give a pulse of a proportional length, if you fed these outputs to solenoid valves they would give you different proportions of both fluids

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please can you expand your question (not comments) to explain your background, capabilities, experience of building electronics and also your application timing etc. requirements. As it stands, your question is too vague to answer well. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks @TonyM. I have tried to update the question with a bit more clarification. But my preliminary knowledge or the lack thereof limits the specifics I can provide at the moment. I understand asking a circuit diagram is a tall order.

Comment: There are three or four MAJOR aspects to this design, and each one is worthy of it's own question.  You'll need at least two actuators to enable different proportions of fluids, you'll need drivers for those actuators, you'll likely need signal processing on the proximity sensor,....

Comment: If you're looking for someone to post the whole design, this isn't the right forum.  If you're looking for guidance in what you need to learn, your FASTEST approach would be to learn how to program a microcontroller.  The Arduino (as one among many microcontroller dev boards) would be a great platform for you to start with.

Comment: Even then, this would only make some on the design aspects easier.  Others, like the driver for your actuators, would remain at the same level of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding to an answer,

Here would be the example circuit from falstads circuit simulator, its not a perfect sum, but it would fill the role, the value of the potentiometer controls how wide a variation you can control, you would just use a push button to trigger both after selecting the ratio you want.

[image]

[Falstad Circuit Simultor Link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+56+5+50%0A165+0+144+112+144+4+0%0Aw+0+176+0+272+0%0Aw+0+176+-32+176+0%0Aw+0+240+-80+240+0%0Aw+-32+176+-32+272+0%0Ac+-32+272+-32+320+0+0.000009999999999999999+0.014046916701783974%0Ag+-32+320+-32+336+0%0Ar+-32+176+-32+96+0+1000%0Aw+-32+112+64+112+0%0AR+-80+112+-160+112+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0AO+128+208+192+208+0%0Ar+-80+112+-80+240+0+100%0Aw+-80+112+-32+112+0%0Ac+-80+240+-128+240+0+0.00001+3.5438318946034997e-13%0AL+-128+240+-160+240+0+1+true+5+0%0Ag+96+304+96+320+0%0Aw+64+112+128+112+0%0Aw+128+112+128+176+0%0Aw+496+112+496+176+0%0Aw+432+112+496+112+0%0Ag+464+304+464+320+0%0Ac+288+240+240+240+0+0.00001+3.5438318946034997e-13%0Aw+288+112+336+112+0%0Ar+288+112+288+240+0+100%0AO+496+208+560+208+0%0AR+288+112+208+112+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Aw+336+112+432+112+0%0Ar+336+176+336+0+0+1000%0Ag+336+320+336+336+0%0Ac+336+272+336+320+0+0.000009999999999999999+0.01444877907816789%0Aw+336+176+336+272+0%0Aw+368+240+288+240+0%0Aw+368+176+336+176+0%0Aw+368+176+368+272+0%0A165+368+144+480+144+4+0%0A174+176+0+112+80+1+5000+0.49010000000000004+Proportion%0Aw+-80+112+-80+48+0%0Aw+112+48+-80+48+0%0Aw+336+0+176+0+0%0Aw+-32+96+176+96+0%0Aw+240+240+208+240+0%0Aw+208+240+208+400+0%0Aw+208+400+-128+400+0%0Aw+-128+400+-128+240+0%0Ao+10+64+0+4102+5+0.00009765625+0+1%0Ao+24+64+0+4098+5+0.1+1+1%0Ah+2+7+5%0A)

Failure point would be if the potentiometer went open circuit the circuit would never turn off, for this you could use a third fixed monostable to supply a ground to your solenoids so even if it gets stuck on, it acts as a timeout,